# What is 500K in Bitcoin?

Tags: client

Many times I see something like this `500K` or `2Bytes`.
What are those in bitcoin and how can I calculate them.

Sorry for this noob question ;)

Comment: Context needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`k` is [kilo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilo-) and refers to 1,000. `500k` are 500,000. This can have a lot of use cases, sometimes one wants to sell 500k Bitcoin (unlikely) and sometimes users refer to exchange rates in Satoshi: 500k Satoshi basicly mean you can buy something at the rate of 0.005 Bitcoin (`0.00500000`).

`2Bytes` are two [units of digital information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte). It tells you how much space is required to store two characters like `OK` on a disk or in memory. 2 Bytes can be broken down into 16 Bit of plain binary information. I'm not sure in which context this could be related to anything Bitcoin-specific. Maybe you add an example reference.

Comment: kB is also often (wrongly) shortened to just K (and thereby wrongly capitalized). Without context it's impossible to know what the OP is asking about.